# How can I add trust store in SSLSocketFactory in Android?

Tags: android, ssl

I'm writing an Android's app with SSL connection (not HTTP). I read a lot of tutorials about HTTPS in Android but it keeping product error "SSL socket factory is abstract cannot be instantiated." with `SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(truststore)`. 
My question is: How can I add key store to Android?.
This is my example:

```
public void run() {
 try {
      KeyStore trusted = KeyStore.getInstance("BKS");
      InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);
       try {
           trusted.load(in, "1234567".toCharArray());
           SSLSocketFactory sSLSocketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault(); // <<<<< Line 40
           SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sSLSocketFactory.createSocket("10.0.2.2", 9998);
           sslSocket.startHandshake();
           Log.i("SSLsocket", "true");
            } finally {
                in.close();
            }    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
                      at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:322)
                      at com.example.begood.voip.SSlconnection.run(SSlconnection.java:40)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, given your trustStore:

```
KeyManagerFactory kmfactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
                              KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
kmfactory.init(trustStore, "password".toCharArray());
KeyManager[] keymanagers =  kmfactory.getKeyManagers();

TrustManagerFactory tmf=TrustManagerFactory
  .getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());

tmf.init(trustStore);

SSLContext sslContext=SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");

sslContext.init(keymanagers, tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

SSLSocketFactory factory=sslContext.getSocketFactory();
```

Comment: Android doesn't have folder trust store. You must have `InputStream in = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.keystore);`